# Authorizing to a LAN when logging to the computer

Tags: authentication, networking, dhcp

Please follow the scenario below:

1) I connect my computer to LAN via ethernet.
2) I open my computer. 
3) I enter my login name and password.
4) Computer is logged in and connected to the internet automatically.

I'm wondering the procedure when a computer is connecting to the internet.

As far as I know, when I open my computer, 
1) DHCP client is started, 
2) This client gets an IP from DHCP server.

Sometimes, especially computers with Windows operating system, when we login to our computer, the computer is also authenticated at the network as well. So in this situation, does the computer sends the credentials to DHCP server?

Any kind of help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too general (there are many different ways to implement network authentication), however I'll answer the question:

> How do Windows clients authenticate on a network in the most common
>   case?

Generally, Windows networks utilize a domain server for authentication. This is often the same machine that does DHCP, but it doesn't have to be. More information can be found on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP Server in Windows is not checking for authentication or any kinds like that. The DHCP Server itself is only managed by Authorized server list by Domain Controller. Even an unauthorized client requests an IP from that DHCP Server, the server still issues an IP to that client.

If you want to authenticate at that layer 2 or 3 level, I think some other authentication methods might help such as port security, dynamic VLAN, ...

Comment: The OP should post the class of DHCP controller.  If it is a garden-variety home router, then the DHCP controller does not check for authentication.  On the other, wifi on my employer's network (large company) use a form of Windows Domain Controller authentication to authorize wifi access.  More often then not though, if you have physical access to the network (ethernet jack), then an ethernet connected device will be assigned an IP address.